# Double modification by percentage

Tags: java, math, double, decimal, percentage

I am trying to modify a double by a percentage.

### Example

I have the double 10.0.

I need to modify this double by a percentage to get the following output:

```
Example Output:
50% -> 20.0
75% -> 15.0
100% -> 10.0
200% -> 5.0
```

How would I be able to do this and is there a mathematical term for this?

Comment: Those seem reversed.  Would 200% of 10 be 20?  And 50% of 10 be 5?  I'm confused as to what sort of percent these are.

Comment: Multiplication is the term for it. A percentage is defined as a fraction of 100, so to get the percentage x of any number, multiply by x/100.

Comment: @markspace 50 % of 20 is 10, 75 % of 15 is 10, 100 % of 10 is 10 and 200 % of 5 is 10.

Comment: 75% -15.0  ??? what Math did he study in school?university))

Comment: Anyway welcome to StackOverflow! Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.

Comment: To get the output shown in question for value 10, all you have to do is divide 10 by the fraction (percentage number/100).

Comment: @user3284549 Sorry if the question was unclear, this is my first time posting on stackoverflow. I have marked the answer that worked below. If you can think of a better term than "modify", I will be sure to update the post so that other users can read it more clearly. Thanks!

Comment: It was pretty clear in the end anyway, with the example I guess. Just a bit confused by what you meant with "modify by a percentage" at first. What you're actually doing is finding the output that results in the input value when multiplied with the given percentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java will be something like this

```
double percentage = Double.parseDouble(percentageValue.substring("%", "")) / 100;
double d = doubleValue;
double result = d / percentage;
```

This allows you to do this:

```
input: percentageValue, doubleValue
output: result
```

test:

```
input: 100%, 20
output: 10
```

I don't think there is a term. (Someone correct me if I am wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple division:

```
System.out.println(10D / 0.5);   // 20.0
System.out.println(10D / 0.75);  // 15.0
System.out.println(10D / 1);     // 10.0
System.out.println(10D / 2);     // 5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Way:

```
double startValue = 10;
double percent = 50;
double tempValue = startValue * (percent*.01);
double finalValue = startValue + tempValue;
```